# How to share the onedrive file to the people outside of organization

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a scenario as below:

I have a website and we used the MS Graph API to connect the OneDrive.

The question is when we create a file or files, I want to share it to some one to read it.

If the person is part of organization, it works well. But if a user is not the member in my organization, I get an access denied.

Does anyone know how to connect with anonymous user also authorized user within a same one-drive.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to share the file to anyone without needing to sing in?

Comment: There isn't enough information to go on. Please edit your question to include your current configuration (i.e. is OD configured to _support_ external sharing), sample code, and the exception/payload you're receiving as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to create a share file to someone that outside of organization.

We can create a sharelink for a file when we create it by using the following API: `POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/createLink` or `POST /me/drive/items/{itemId}/createLink`

In the request body, we should set the `scope` property to `anonymous` so that anyone can use the link to get access.

And we can set `type` to `view` to create a read-only link to this file.

Comment: Hi Kang, Thank you for your reply. just a quick question, if i set scope to anonymous, will it affect my already logged in user to access the drive? Thanks

Comment: If you set scope to anonymous, anyone with the link has access, without needing to sign in. This may include people outside of your organization. So it does not affect the user has logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it is what i needed.